# How do I force Firefox to download an .xml file instead of opening it?

Tags: firefox, xml

I am using Firefox 83.0(64-bit) on a Windows 10 PC. I am trying to download an .xml file instead of opening it as a browser page. However, Firefox keeps opening it in the browser. I have tried:

1. Going into General, Applications, changing the Action to Save File for "Extensible Markup Language (XML)", and then re-opening the link. Originally the Action was to open in Firefox.
2. Clearing my browsing history, and then re-opening the link.
3. Trying to Save As on the .xml page in Firefox, and then doing "Save as", only to find that .xml is not an option.
4. Closing down Firefox and then reopening it.

I found [this older question](https://superuser.com/questions/282146/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-open-xml-files-in-notepad-instead-of-in-the-browser/282147#282147) about the same problem. However, this is dated from 2011 and I assume a new method has been implemented in the intervening 9 years.

I managed to download the .xml using Chrome, without any problem.

How do I force Firefox to do the download?

Comment: I had no problem in Firefox when using Save As on an .xml link.

Comment: I think that was the one thing I didn't try after changing the setting. Thank you!

Comment: Save As from the File menu also worked when displaying an xml file.

Comment: Some time you might don't want to download PDF or image files rather then that you just want to `view` it in that case let it be as it is and download a download manager like https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/ in order to download just copy and paste the URL in `free download manager`.

Answer (score 3):

Open about:preferences -> Applications. On Extensible Markup Language (xml) action, select "Save File". It's supposed to work "as is". If it's not the case, you installation may have some problem to handle this file. Try reinstall it.